# How to place N divs next to each other (in a PHP foreach)?

Tags: css-float, html

I have to place an unlimited number of divs next to each other, in a PHP foreach loop. I already have the code which creates divs and the content of the divs, the only thing I need to know now is, how to place them next to each other, on one lije so to say. I think float is the keyword? I am missing the right idea at the moment. The content of each of the divs is a ul list:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Give the divs this CSS rule: `display: inline-block; float: left`. They will be placed side by side, just like text characters.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion the best way is to use CSS and "inline"

```
<style>
ul#display-inline-block-example,
ul#display-inline-block-example li {        
/* Setting a common base */         
margin: 0;
padding: 0;     }

ul#display-inline-block-example li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
} 
</style>

<ul id="display-inline-block-example">
<li>Item one</li>
<li>Item two</li>
<li>Item three</li>
```

http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/